# How to get a value from a map inside a map in drools

Tags: drools

I have a Main map object inside it contains another map. Now i need to get the value from it in drools?
My code looks like

```
HashMap<String,Object> studentsMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
HashMap<String,int> marksMap = new HashMap<String,int>();
marksMap.put("Maths",98);
marksMap.put("Chemistry",96);
studentsMap.put("JohnDoe", marksMap);
```

I am inserting this 'studentsMap' object to the drools session and firing the rules.
How to compare marks values in drools (How to check condition if mark is greater than 90)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proposed solutions did not worked for me.

You need to call map differently in eval.

```
rule "studentsMap"

when
  Student($marks : markMap)
  eval((int)$marks.get("Maths") > 90)
 then
  System.out.println("mark greater than 90");
end
```

Also additional casting should be done.

Links: http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/rules-users/2007-November/003921.html

**UPD**: Found more conventional way to do this

```
rule "studentsMap"

when
  $student: Student($marks : markMap, $marks.get("Maths") > 90)
 then
  System.out.println("mark greater than 90");
end
```

You can also perform check for key presence in the map before calling get.

```
  $student: Student($marks : markMap, $marks.containsKey("Maths"), $marks.get("Maths") > 90)
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this yet but may be something like this can be done

`rule "studentsMap"

   when

     entry : Entry() from $studentsMap.entrySet()

     marksMap : Map() from entry.getValue()
     markEntry : Entry() from marksMap.entrySet()
     mark : Number() from markEntry.getValue()

     mark > 90
   then

     System.out.println("mark greater than 90");

 end`

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your Fact name is Student.
The rule will look like this :

```
rule "studentsMap"

when
  Student($markMap : markMaap)
  eval($markMap["Maths"] > 90)
 then

 System.out.println("mark greater than 90");

end
```